# Buffer overflow exception simba JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to insert 1432466 records with 27 columns

```
count=0;
BATCH_SIZE=5000;
while (res.next()) {
preparedStatement.setString(1, res.getString(1));
............
preparedStatement.setString(27, res.getString(27));
preparedStatement.addBatch();
if(count % BATCH_SIZE == BATCH_SIZE-1) {
     preparedStatement.executeBatch();
     preparedStatement.clearBatch();
}
count++;
}
preparedStatement.executeBatch();
```

I'm facing the below exception.

```
java.sql.SQLException: [JDBC4ClientDSII]java.nio.BufferOverflowException at com.simba.client.dataengine.SCQueryExecutor.execute(Unknown Source) at com.simba.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.executePreparedAnyBatch(Unknown Source) at com.simba.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.executeBatch(Unknown Source) at HiveTSConnector.main(HiveTSConnector.java:105) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.BufferOverflowException ... 4 more
```

Comment: You're supposed to execute batches every few dozen rows, not putting a million and a half in the same batch.

Comment: Can I get any code?

Comment: Sure, `System.out.println("The modulo operator % can be of help!");`.

Comment: @Kayaman Please see my edit

Comment: You don't need `clearBatch()` and your batch size is still two orders of magnitude too high.

Comment: I tried with 1000 too. Shuld it be still low?

Comment: I said few dozen. Dozen = 12, few = 2-3.